# How to read the first column of csv file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

Assuming that I have this kind of CSV file which looks like:

```
age       1

gender    2

location  3

address   4
```

How do I retrieve all the strings from the first column? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on how your CSV data looks like.. nonetheless, look into [`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and try an approach, among googling, before asking for a solution and coming empty-handed.

Comment: Please elaborate more on the info.
Do you want to read the file using javascript?

Comment: I want to retrieve all the values from the first column using javascript or jquery. However, I only managed to read the last rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    success: function(response) {
       readCSVFile(response);
    }
});
```

Handle your response from the ajax call.

```
function readCSVFile(response) {
    var lines = response.split("\n");

    for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
       var _firstColumn = lines[i].split(";")[0];     //First column (Split on the separator!)

       //Do your stuff
    }
};
```